# How to run a bash script by double clicking by entering the path in sudoers?

Tags: command-line, sudo, sudoedit

Using `sudo visudo` I add the line `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/script.sh` in `sudoers` but the **script.sh** does not run on double click.
If I add the line `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` in `sudoers` then the **script.sh** runs and works when double clicked. How can do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `/home/user` in your ordinary user's `$PATH`?

Comment: If you're using `sudo`, it's apparently to prevent users from having complete access to superuser privileges.  Yet you're giving `sudo` the ability to run a script located in a directory controlled by one user.  That one user can change the script to anything desired and now has complete access to superuser privileges - and can give those privileges to anyone else.

Comment: Your specific line in `sudoers` allows running this exact file with `sudo`, but double-clicking does not run the script with `sudo`. If there are `sudo` commands *inside* the script then double-clicking probably results in running them eventually; these are the commands you should consider allowing in `sudoers`. Allowing `sudo /home/user/script.sh` does not magically allow every `sudo` command from within the script when the script itself is run without `sudo`. Is this what happens? Are there `sudo` command(s) inside the script?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski There are commands inside the script that only work with `sudo`, such as `ip tuntap add dev`, `route add`. I tried both with and without `sudo`, the **script .sh** does not run in either case. And when you add `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` it runs and works.

Comment: @Andrew Henle In this case, you can set root permissions to read and modify the file.

Comment: @moninah So what?  The owner of the directory can delete it or rename it and then put another file in its place.

Comment: @moninah you have to delete spaces in a user name when addressing a user, like this `@AndrewHenle`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Put the script.sh in `/root/bin/`, `chmod 700`, make sure the file is owned by `root`, remove the `sudo` commands from it.

Comment: @moninah Having the script owned by root does not give it any privileges to run as root except that the user now has to log in as root to access the script - no easily done on most windowing systems.

Comment: Would it work for you to put the line `[[ $UID -ne 0 ]] && exec sudo $0 "$@"` as the first executable line in the script? This forces the script to be run either as `root` or under `sudo`.

Comment: @doneal24 Thank you! The launch of a double click is now working! So it turns out there are no ways to make a safe launch of a double click? The only way is only enter into the terminal `sudo sh '/path/to/script.sh'`?

Comment: @doneal24 could you please post that as an answer as it seems to have been what the OP was after?

Comment: @moninah I've added my comment as an answer. If it does solve your problem, please accept the answer so that it comes up in searches more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting my comment as an answer. Add this line as the first executable statement in your script

```
[[ $UID -ne 0 ]] && exec sudo $0 "$@"
```

This checks to see if you're running as root and restarted the script under `sudo` with the same arguments. Normal precautions and warnings apply in configuring sudo and with running things as root.

Comment: As I understand it, This only works if you follow this code with `sudo -s <<END <command ...> END`. Adding `sudo` to every command doesn't work. For some reason the commands are not processed like `sudo`.

Comment: @moninah You are adding `sudo` once inside the script. Assuming that you have sudo rights to run the script and all commands in the script are in root's PATH and you don't have any aliases that you use it should run. What error message do you get when you add this one line to your script?

Comment: I don't know what it was connected with, but now if add to each command `sudo`, then everything works. And if add once `sudo`, then it also works.