# How to run the command "sudo sh /path/to/script.sh" by double clicking?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a question from this thread [How to run a bash script by double clicking by entering the path in sudoers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762272/how-to-run-a-bash-script-by-double-clicking-by-entering-the-path-in-sudoers). Since it was explained to me that it is unsafe to grant `sudo` privileges to the `script.sh` file, I decided to find a way to double-click the `script.sh` file without granting `sudo` privileges to the file itself. **And to make it safe**.

I'm using Debian 12 with the KDE Plasma desktop environment. To run the command `sudo sh /path/to/script.sh`, you need to go to a terminal, type `sudo sh /path/to/script.sh`, and then enter the password. I want to have a file I can double click in the UI which will then run the `sudo sh /path/to/script.sh`, so all I need to do after double clicking is just enter the password.

There are commands inside the script that only work with `sudo`, such as `ip tuntap add dev`,, or `route add`. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

Since you edited your comment to provide more information, I can now give you a complete answer. I verified with my friend who runs KDE plasma, and he says that the default behavior is that double-clicking a script on the desktop will launch it, provided that the executable bit is set. It doesn't launch it in a terminal, so the script has to create its own terminal. With that in mind, here are the instructions:

1. Add a shebang to your script

Add the line `#!/bin/sh` to the very start of your script. This tells you system which shell to use to execute your file.

2. Make the file executable

Right click on the file and under `permissions`, tick the checkbox that says `executable`. Alternatively, run `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`.

3. Prefix every command (that requires it) with `sudo` inside the script
4. Make sure the script opens in a terminal

You can do this by adding the following snippet at the start of your script (but after the shebang):

```
test "$IN_TERM" || {
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole --hold -e "$0"
    exit 0
} && true
```

This uses Konsole, KDE's default terminal. The `--hold` flag makes sure that the terminal stays open after the script is finished, so that you can verify that it runs correctly.

That's it, everything should work!

### Example

Just to get an overview of what everything should look like, here is a similar script I have on my system. Instead of changing network settings, it changes my laptop's charging behavior, but the overall idea is similar.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x  # Print all commands before running them
set -e  # Exit on first error

test "$IN_TERM" || {
    export IN_TERM=1
    alacritty --hold -e "$0"  # I use alacritty as my terminal.
    exit 0
} && true

sudo -v  # Ask for password, but don't run any command

# Subsequent invocations of `sudo` won't ask for password
sudo tpacpi-bat -s ST 1 0
sudo tpacpi-bat -s SP 1 0

echo 'Done!'
```

### Security

In the comments, you were mentioning that you were worried about putting `sudo` inside the script itself. I'm not a security researcher, but let me assure you that this is completely fine and secure. `sudo` will still prompt the user for the password. Any other user on the system, or a malicious program running with your user's permissions, won't be able to take advantage of your script in any way. Putting `sudo` in scripts may be frowned upon, but for reasons unrelated to security (e.g. putting `sudo` in a script may be problematic if you intend to distribute this script to other people, since not everybody has `sudo` installed).

## Old answer

As the comments pointed out, we can't really help you, since you didn't tell us what distro / desktop environment you're using.

However, I can give you some pointers.

### Move the `sudo` inside the script

I think in this situation it would be best for you to move the `sudo` invocation into the script itself. You can do it by putting something like this at the start of the script:

```
test "$(id -u)" -eq 0 || {
    sudo sh "$0"
    exit 0
}
```

Another option is to create a second script that launches the first with `sudo`. And a third option is to simply prefix any of the root-only commands in your script with `sudo`. It will only ask for the password once.

### Set the executable bit

In the terminal, run `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`. This makes the file executable. You can test that it works by launching the script with `/path/to/script.sh` as opposed to `sh /path/to/script.sh`. In some desktop environments, this may also make the script runnable by double-clicking it through the GUI.

### Set the correct shebang

Make sure your script starts with `#!/bin/sh` (or `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) if you script uses bash-only features)

### Dig around in your distro's settings app

Double clicking to launch scripts may be disabled due to security reasons. Try looking for this option in your file managers or desktop environments settings. Here

### Create a `.desktop` file.

If the above fails, you can create a file called `myscript.desktop` with the following contents (and edit the `Type`, `Comment`, and `Exec` fields):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=your_human_friendly_name
Comment=your_human_friendly_comment
Exec=/path/to/script.sh
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Application;
```

You can now double-click this file to run your script. Note that you will need to move the `sudo` into your script. If you need your script to launch inside a terminal, change the `Terminal` field. Note that your script needs to have the executable bit set for this approach to work.

Another bonus of `.desktop` files is that if you put it into `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`, it will also be accessible through your application launcher.

Also, there is a tool called `gendesk` to automatically make `.dekstop` files for you, but writing them by hand also works.

### Use `gksudo`

If you do figure out how to achieve the behavior that you want, it may still be impossible to run your script if your desktop environment launches it without a terminal, since there would be no way for you to type your password for `sudo`. Consider installing the package `gksudo` (may have a different name depending on distro) and using it instead of `sudo`. It works the same way, but creates a GUI password entry box instead of using the terminal

### Make the script launch its own terminal

In case you need the script to launch in a terminal for reasons other than interacting with `sudo` (e.g. displaying output to the user), you can put this at the beginning of your script (but after the shebang) to make sure it always launches in the terminal:

```
test "$IN_TERM" || {
    export IN_TERM=1
    alacritty --hold -e "$0"
    exit 0
} && true
```

Please note that the above snippet uses `alacritty`, which is my preferred terminal. Change that to whatever terminal you use. Also note the `--hold` and `-e` flags, which are also alacritty-specific. `-e` is actually `-c` on most other terminals.

### Use `rofi`

This doesn't answer your question, but I think you might find it useful. If you find yourself having a lot of different scripts that you need to be able to launch quickly, consider `rofi`. It will allow you to have a searchable menu of all your scripts, ready to launch. To use rofi this way, you first need to create a script (let's call it `rofi_launch.sh`) that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    ls /path/to/where/you/store/your/scripts
else
    FILE="/path/to/where/you/store/your/scripts/$1"
    killall rofi
    "$FILE" & disown
fi
```

Then, launch rofi with `rofi -show RUN:/path/to/rofi_launch.sh` (you can bind this to a keyboard shortcut in your desktop environment's settings) and you should have a menu from where you can launch any of your scripts.

Comment: I have a question from this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762272/how-to-run-a-bash-script-by-double-clicking-by-entering-the-path-in-sudoers. Since it was explained to me that it is unsafe to grant ```sudo``` privileges to the ```script.sh``` file, I decided to find a way to double-click the ```script.sh``` file without granting ```sudo``` privileges to the file itself. **And to make it safe**. There are commands inside the script that only work with sudo, such as ```ip tuntap add dev```, ```route add```.

Comment: @moninah that makes absolutely no difference to security. What is unsafe is to allow users to run the script _without_ requiring `sudo`, which is what your original question was asking.

Comment: @terdon So I want to run a bash file without adding it to `sudoers` (because it's not secure). But also so as not to constantly open the terminal and type commands first and then the password. I would like to put commands into a bash file and double-click on it and type the password.

Comment: Yes, isn't this what this answer provides? Maybe you missed it because the answer gives a lot of useful information, but if you create a `.desktop` file (see "Create a .desktop file" in the answer) and use `sudo sh /path/to/script.sh`, and set `Terminal=true`, then you will be able to do exactly what you say.

Comment: @renzev This code displays a console and a password field, but commands that work with sudo do not run:
`test "$IN_TERM" || {
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole --hold -e "$0"
    exit 0
} && true`
`sudo -v` `<command ...>`.
  
By creating a shortcut and specifying `Terminal=true`, the script starts and works. As I understand it, with the shortcut you can simply use the command `sudo -s <<EOF <command ...> EOF`. But I would like to be able to run the script without creating a shortcut.

Comment: Hmmm. `sudo -v` is not strictly required, try without it. And each command that you need to run with root privileges should have `sudo` in front of it, on the same line (same way you'd run it interactively in the terminal).

Comment: @renzev Yes, it was necessary to add `sudo` to each command. In order not to add to each command, but to add to all at once, I did the following: `#!/bin/sh`
`test "$IN_TERM" || {
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
} && true`
`sudo -s <<EOF <command ...> EOF`. I also wanted to ask you why the command starts with a `test`? I've often seen `if` and `fi` tags used in things like this. Can the command be somehow changed to use `if` and `fi`?

Comment: I am unsure whether the `sudo -s` approach would work, I have never tried it. First try adding `sudo` individually, and see if that helps. I used the `test` command because that's what I prefer, but you can probably use `if` and `fi` as well. EDIT my usage of `test` is informed by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0KKBmfiVl0), but obviously feel free to use whatever style you prefer.

Comment: @renzev Could you write what the command should look like using the `if` and `fi` tags?

Comment: It would look like `if [ -n "$IN_TERM" ]; then export IN_TERM=1; konsole -e "$0"; exit 0; fi`. You may replace the semicolons with line breaks. You may also put a line break directly after `then`, but it is not required.

Comment: @renzev That doesn't work for me. And I tried options with line breaks and line breaks. Is it working for you? I preferred to do it this way `if [[ -z "$IN_TERM" ]]; then
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
fi`

Comment: After numerous attempts, I realized that simply adding `sudo` to every command would not work. For some reason the commands are not processed like `sudo`. The only way that works for me is `test "$IN_TERM" || {     export IN_TERM=1     konsole -e "$0"     exit 0 } && true sudo -s <<EOF <command ...> EOF`.

Comment: I don't know what it was connected with, but now if add to each command `sudo`, then everything works.